# Run sql migrations on a clone of Postgres RDS then use that as master

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have been trying to figure out if there is a way to do the following scenario in `Postgres` on `Amazon RDS`:

1. Clone a production database (we have several shards across multiple regions), **while keeping it in sync**
2. Run some SQL queries to update the data in the clone (they are potentially risky and thus we need to do this on a separate database)
3. Run a test app instance connected to that database and do some synthetic checks and validations
4. If everything goes well, promote the clone to be master stop using old master and it's replicas

I see there are ways to create `Read Replicas` but they aren't quite helpful as I need to run some upgrades on the replica so it has to be writable.

So basically I need a sleeping clone that isn't used for reads but kept in sync and I can perform some modifications on.

Is this possible using `AWS RDS`?

Answer (score 0):

One solution which I can think of is

1. Use a custom domain name for connecting to your database. Map the custom domain name to the database domain name using CNAME.
2. Create a new RDS instance from the latest snapshot.
3. Perform the DML operation and testing on the new database.
4. Once the test is successful promote the new database in Route53.

For using a custom domain name, please check https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-rds-db.html

Comment: the problem with that is that it won't be in sync, and newly written data during the operation will be lost

Comment: that will always be there when performing check it will be some point in time. it won't be realtime.